# Rails tutorial, odd CSS formatting on site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, blueprint-css

You can see it [here](http://blazing-fog-1717.herokuapp.com/).

The site looks fine when I remove Blueprint. I've tried adding Bootstrap and the same issue occurs.

I've been following [this (excellent) tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book?version=3.2#top).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, try to add the following line to *config/environments/production.rb*

```
config.assets.precompile += [ "blueprint/*.css" ]
```

This step is described in section [5.4.3 Deploying to production with Blueprint](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/book/ruby-on-rails-tutorial?version=3.2#sec%3adeploying_to_production_with_blueprint) ;)

Comment: Good suggestion, but I already had that line in the file. I even tried to pre-compile prior to pushing to Heroku. The display looks the same even with dev/test. I pre-compiled bootstrap and everything looks fine now. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

According to chrome, this is the code causing this:

```
http://blazing-fog-1717.herokuapp.com/assets/application-fcc74be8bd91511db934f033390efd28.css

a:link::after, a:visited::after {
  content: " (" attr(href) ")";
  [...]
```

I have no idea why blueprint might be doing this, but you can just edit blueprint.css and remove the following rule:

```
content: " (" attr(href) ")";
```

Setting the media attribute of your links to print (media="print") can fix the problem as well.

If you don't like either of these solution, you should be able to over-write the css by adding the following CSS code AFTER the inclusion blueprint:

```
a:link:after, a:visited:after {
  font-size:90%;
  content: none;
}
```

I'm not sure about that last part, but you could try it out.

Comment: I had them separately defined but the pre-compile step was putting them both in the application.css file. I guess it was being done incorrectly. I pre-compiled bootstrap and everything looks fine now. Thanks for your help.